# Function get selected text in EditBox winApit

Tags: c, winforms, winapi

Is there any WinAPI to get the selected text in an Edit Box?
Take the initial and final position of the cursor?
A function where I tell the HWND of editbox and the function return, the selected text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of a single function that does this.

Send the [EM_GETSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to an edit control to get the limits of the selection, e.g.

```
DWORD selStart;
DWORD selEnd;
SendMessage(hWndEdit, EM_GETSEL, &selStart, &selEnd);
```

Use [WM_GETTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve all the text from the edit control, and extract the selected substring yourself.